# how to code a batch file to automate django web server start

Tags: django, file, batch-file

i really need a code sample to  automate starting Django  development webserver  "python manage.py runserver" in a .bat file in windows . I have python26 and django 1.1.1 in installed

Thanks

i meant by automate is clicking on the .bat file and the Django development webserver start up
and i have no batch file scripting knowledge will love to get a code sample

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write a `.bat` file containing:

```
cd <location of your django project>
<location of python.exe> manage.py runserver
```

I believe that should suffice.

Comment: The code is just like that... all you have to do is replace what's inside the <>s. Location of python.exe should be something like `"C:\Program Files\Python\python-2.6.1\python.exe"` but will depend on your installation. Similarly, django project location is the folder where your django project is.

Comment: how can i do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

As Miguel said, you can write the below lines:

```
cd <location of your django project>

<location of python.exe> manage.py runserver
```

in a file and save it as somefilename.bat, thats it. Now, its a batch file and clicking on it would execute it i.e. your runserver command.

What do you mean by batch file scripting?

Answer (score 2):

Miguel and Ankit already answered you. I just followed it and it worked. Here is my complete offeronline.bat

```
D:
cd user\shumon\offeronline 
manage.py runserver
```

My Django project and python files are in the D drive.

- `D:` changes the current directory to D
- the next command `cd ...` changes the current directory to the exact location of the project.
- `manage.py runserver` runs the server.