# How to run django server with ACTIVATED virtualenv using batch file (.bat)

Tags: python, django, windows, batch-file

I found this post to be useful on [how to code a batch file to automate django web server start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027160/how-to-code-a-batch-file-to-automate-django-web-server-start).

But the problem is, there is **no virtualenv** activated, How can i activate it before the manage.py runserver inside the script?

#### I would like to run this server with virtualenv activated via batch file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my solution by encoding this:

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d C:\path\to\your\env\scripts & activate & cd /d C:\path\to\your\env\[projectname] & python manage.py runserver"
```

Comment: This solution work for me,  If your folder name have space doesn't matter. example :  `cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\[user]\path\to\my folder name with space\env\scripts & activate & cd /d C:\Users\[user]\path\to\your\env\[projectname] & python manage.py runserver" `

Answer (score 5):

Call the `activate.bat` script in your batch file, before you run `manage.py`,

```
CALL \path\to\env\Scripts\activate.bat
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

try `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate`

and look at [virtualenv docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this script is good for ubuntu and i am looking for windows

Comment: From docs:  "On Windows, the equivalent activate script is in the Scripts folder:> \path\to\env\Scripts\activate"

Comment: also you can try to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win on windows and activate your virtualenv with `workon` keyword

Comment: i tried and tried but it doesnt work. but i just solve my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927567/a-python-script-that-activates-the-virtualenv-and-then-runs-another-python-scrip

Comment: yeah, looks like it *.bat features, sorry that misled

Answer (score 0):

If your virtualenv is created via virtualenvwrapper:

```
workon yourenvname & python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to **use absolute path to python** in order to run "manage.py".

```
cmd /k "cd /d C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts & activate & python C:\path\to\project\manage.py runserver"
```

where `& activate` runs `C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\activate.bat`
and `& python` runs python at `C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\python`

**you get the same result with:**

```
call "C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\activate.bat"
C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\python "C:\path\to\project\manage.py" runserver
```

I guess my problem is that i have many pythons installed